# Run a sql script in c# (.asp net)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, directory, sqlconnection

I just want the directory to open to "project_name\Scripts(sub_folder)\merge.sql"

I can't get rid of 'C:' and I cant get the actually data file to appear.

I received an"System.io.directorynotfoundexcpetion".

Here's my code:

```
private void MergeQuery()
        {
            //might need to change C: drive directory
            //string derefQuery = @"\.\mergeSQL.sql";
            using (SqlConnection mer = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = address_name; Initial Catalog = catalog_name; Integrated Security=SSPI"))
            {
                {
                    mer.Open();
                    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName("\\project_name\\Scripts\\mergeSQL.sql ");
                    string mergeScript = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

                    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> commandStrings = Regex.Split(mergeScript, @"^\s*GO\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    foreach (string commandString in commandStrings)
                    {
                        if (commandString.Trim() != "")
                        {
                            using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandString, mer))
                            {
                                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            Label2.Text = "Query merged";
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: I wrote an answer and then  saw this is asp.net so my answer is useless. :) Where is that mergeSQL.sql file located, relative to web site's root path?

Comment: the wwwroot folder is location in my c: drive. The SQL file is located in a 2 subfolders after ending the wwwroot folder.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. web root is in www and script is in `c:\wwwroot\project_name\Scripts\mergescript.sql` and your asp.net app is in `c:\wwwroot\project_name?`

Comment: the asp.net app is in my C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app.publish. The SQL script is in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app.publish\Scripts. However I went back into debug state when trying to solve the issue. "Path" is still putting the full directory. Should I try to republish?

Comment: No need for republish. Take a look at my answer, I think that solves your problem

Comment: unfortunley not. This is what Path is display now: "C:\Users\vincentt\Documents\overall_project_folder\project_folder\project_folder\Scripts\mergeSQL.sql" . I just want it to display "Scripts\mergeSQL.sql"

Answer (score 0):

first, there is an error in line

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName("\\project_name\\Scripts\\mergeSQL.sql ");
```

In that line you're getting directory path from file path, so `path` variable becomes `\\project_name\\Scripts\\` or something similar. On next line you're trying to read file from that path variable, not from file.

What you need is to get path relative to web site root and then read file, like this

```
string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Scripts/mergeSQL.sql ");
string mergeScript = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
```

this way asp.net will get correct path from your website root's subfolder.